# How to add new relationship in MERGE ON CREATE SET query in neo4j

Tags: neo4j

I have a MERGE query in which i want to merge a node if it exists or create a new node and if a new node is created then create a new relationship linking to the newly created node and add properties to the relationship linked node

basically something like this:

```
MERGE ( user:USER { userId : userId } ) 
ON CREATE SET 
    user.password = password ,
    user.userID = userID ,
    (user)-[:INFO]->(userInfo:PROFILEINFO {firstname:'John',lastName:'Doe'})
RETURN user
```

however i cant figure out how to create a new relationship as this shows an error.

I need to update a userInfo if user inputs new info or update the relationship or create a new user if user does not exist and then create relationship as well.

Comment: The relationship to update, is that the same relationship that you would create if the usre was freshly created? If so, wouldn't a merge of the relationship work just as well? Also, is there any particular reason for keeping first and last name in a separate node from :USER?

Comment: @InverseFalcon yeah i think creating a relationship in the merge would produce the desired effect.I'll try and get back to you.
Also i divided that because i will specify different info nodes for each user that have same relation like :PROFILEINFO, :PRIVACYINFO, :SECURITYINFO and all are types of :INFO of users so i thought of breaking things up rather than have it all in a single node
I guess this does create unnecessary nodes.

Comment: @InverseFalcon what structure should i follow? Do i divide the info in different nodes or create a big properties object that holds all the info for that user.including the profile , settings, privacy, account and such

Comment: Depends on your use cases and queries, and how your data is modeled. Keeping settings and privacy and account data separate makes sense, since you aren't likely to be querying from or to those nodes except from the user node itself. You may want to think about the implications of keeping :USER and :PROFILEINFO nodes separate, though. If nearly every common query involving a user also includes getting their :PROFILEINFO too, then maybe use a single node for that instead of two, or at least move the commonly accessed data to the same node (name properties and userId, for example).

Comment: @InverseFalcon merge of the relationship worked perfectly thanks!

Answer (score 7):

You can use temporary property and foreach:

```
MERGE ( user:USER { userId : userId } ) 
ON CREATE SET 
    user.password = password ,
    user.userID = userID ,
    user.isCreated = [true]
FOREACH(ifthen in user.isCreated |
    MERGE (user)-[:INFO]->(userInfo:PROFILEINFO {firstname:'John',lastName:'Doe'})
    REMOVE user.isCreated
)
RETURN user
```

Comment: `ifthen in user.isCreated` didn't understand this `ifthen` ?

Comment: @raviyadav This is conditional statement trick in cypher - http://www.markhneedham.com/blog/2014/06/17/neo4j-load-csv-handling-conditionals/

Answer (score 4):

A bit late, but following is what I found

```
    MERGE ( user:USER { userId : userId } ) 
    ON CREATE 
        SET 
            user.password = password ,
            user.userID = userID 
        MERGE (user)-[:INFO]->(userInfo:PROFILEINFO {firstname:'John',lastName:'Doe'})
    RETURN user
```

Basically, ON CREATE is an event, SET is an action so do MERGE

Comment: Don't post in the answer that you are a bit late if the answer has value. Also, you state you found the answer, where did you find that answer?

Comment: Just to make sure, that's not `ON CREATE MERGE`, but rather `ON CREATE SET; MERGE`, i.e. there are two distinct `MERGE` stages in this query and both are executed unconditionally. The second merge is always executed, it is not skipped if the first merge matched.